# Is it a sin to offer only fard salat?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, sunnah, fard

Is it sinful to not offer sunah salat but offer only fard salat?

- e.g to offer 2 faraz in fajar slat?
- to offer 4 fard in zuhar salat?
- to offer 4 fard in asar salat?
- to offer 3 fard in maghrib salat?
- to offer 4 fard + 3 vitar in isha salat?

Comment: You answered your own question. Sunnah = optional, Fard = Mandatory.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim: you mean to say everything prophet muhammad did , its not compulsory to do?

Comment: Not everything, just the sunnah part. He did things that were mandatory like fasting/Hajj.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim ok. But I have heard about fajar that 2 sunnah are compulsory. Can you confirm this? I know they are just 2 sunnah but just want to confirm.

Comment: Also witar has nothing to do with Isha, common misconception. Witar is part of Qiyam Layl (Night prayer).

Comment: @Abdullah . I meant to ask about 2 Sunnah of isha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** This is a controversial topic.</sup>

---

When Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said his companions to do something, by that he meant it. Which means there is no other go for the followers. And that is Fard. But, Sunnah is either what deduced from the behaviour of Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) or if he has explicitly said that it is *'voluntary upon one if he performs so and so act.'*

The high priority / importance of the 2 Rakah Sunnah (<strike>Optional</strike> *The way of the prophet (pbuh)*) which you might of heard is because people say, that he never used to leave those 2 Rakah Sunnah before Fajr's 2 Rakah Fard.

> Is it a sin to offer only fard salat?

As simply asked, when he did not tell us it is compulsory, then as far as I know, it is **not** considered sin ( Conditions apply* *in case if you leave it when you're in a hurry or if it costs you something more important than Sunnah.*)

But, as the definition stands, "Sunnah" is the way of the Prophet (pbuh).

There is a difference in opinions in regards to this issue, whether it is highly advisable, which makes it near compulsory to offer those Sunnah prayers or can we leave them as they're just Sunnah?

Here's the thing. This thing is rather dealt situation based than just general opinion based.

Just imagine, you have old parents to take care of. And leaving them, would cost a lot. But, you just have time to come to the mosque or either pray at home just the 2 rakah Fard. Then????

Serving your parents is to be given top priority than praying Sunnah.

This was just an example. In general, you measure and compare and decide on the spot.

If praying Sunnah is costing you to miss something which is actually Fard and/or highly obligatory/advisable on your part, then it could be simply decided that *you could skip praying Sunnah for now.*

There are Hadith, (I don't perfectly remember, and request someone to cite it for me here), #1, which say that Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) prayed his 2 Rakah Sunnah of Zuhr Salah near the time of Asr (or after completion of it or something like that) cuz he couldn't pray it on time i.e. at the time of Zuhr. #2, Some other people say, that on the day of Qiyamah, there is a possibility that Allah might overlook the mistakes in regards to our Fard Salah in case if we're conscious about our Sunnah Salah.

So, people use the above Hadith to state the importance of Sunnah.

So, it is **highly advisable** for one to pray those Sunnah. But **still**, cannot say that those are compulsory, hence there is no sin in case if you skip them for good. (And it is opinion based if 'Conditions apply' or not)

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Cool ! , yeah. It could be a logical answer that you wrote "it is highly advisable for one to pray those Sunnah. But still, cannot say that those are compulsory, hence there is no sin in case if you skip them for good. (And it is opinion based if 'Conditions apply' or not)" / Meanwhile Shi'a believes that those 17 Rek'ahs are obligatory, and other rek'ahs are considered as a Mustahab (or Mustahab-al-Mo'akad) practice which have plenty of thawab (reward).